# Cannot run VLC after update (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, updates, reset

I have just updated to 2.0.6 and cannot start VLC.

On their site it says: *If VLC doesn't even start anymore, delete VLC's configuration file ...Windows Vista/7: C:\Users\%username%\Application Data\vlc\vlcrc*

Application Data, on the other hand is a "Junction", and, I read [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/5ae36d5d-cb29-49ae-a379-a8be0dde0abc) that *This particular Junction points to the  C:Users\username\AppData\Roaming folder.*

But I have no VLC folder in `C:Users\username\AppData\Roaming` folder.

Comment: The VLC installer has an option to delete these files for you Have you tried to re-run the installer?

Comment: @edwardbackstro: yes, i did, a few times, except that first times i did not. but where are these files?

Comment: @cipricus They're in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming`, as advertised (actually I think they're in a directory `VLC` under `Roaming`) -- ensure you're not leaving out the percent signs, as they denote a Windows environment variable, in this case `%username%` which contains the logged-in user's user name.

Comment: I have 2.0.6 installed and I have `C:\Users\edward\AppData\Roaming\vlc`. Have you tried searching for the file `vlcrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the `%username%\AppData\Roaming\vlc` folder was on `D:` drive instead of `C:`.

(Why? Might be related to the fact that I have moved some folders like the desktop and the documents on the second drive.)

That is why I have not found `vlcrc` on `C:`.

So, I have deleted completely the `\vlc` folder (deleting `vlcrc` might have suffice) and re-installed latest VLC.